# Outlook: GetItemFromID does not work if store Id is given in Partial Cached Exchange Mode

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin

I am trying to retrieve item using  mapiNameSpace.GetItemFromID(entryId, storeID).
I am using partial cached exchange mode( i.e. cache only for a month).
The method works fine for cached items. But when I try it for an item older than a month, below exception is thrown

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x8004010F): The message you specified cannot be found.
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass.GetItemFromID(String EntryIDItem, Object EntryIDStore)
```

But if I try it with only entryID and it is working. But this will be time consuming since it will search all stores.

What could be the reason for the error while using storeID parameter in partial cached mode?

P.S. This problem is only in partial Cached Exchange Mode in outlook account settings. Not when completely ON/OFF

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the store entry id, Outlook does not search though all stores. Outlook calls `IMAPISession::OpenEntry`. If the store was already opened in the current session, it had a chance to register its own entry ids so that the MAPI system knows which store to direct the call to. Otherwise you get "an unknown entry id" error. If the store entry id is specified, it is opened first, and then the message using `IMsgStore::OpenEntry`.

What probably happens in your case, is that the item is opened from the online store, which is expensive since the call goes over the network.

Comment: Thankks. Regarding

Comment: Thanks. So I guess there should not be any performance issues with or without store entry id if the store is already opened in the current session. 

My point was, two items in same folder, one in local cache and the other in online,
I can see that Store-entryId is same for both through OutlookSpy and code. But when calling GetItemFromID with entryId and storeID, the item from online is throwing that exception.

But just using only entryId is working fine.

So is the item in Online version has a different storeEntryId compared to the cached item?

Comment: If the item is only present in the online store, Outlook would have to connect to the server to open it (as opposed to the local OST file), so wouldn't you expect it to take longer?